# Parameter value is out of range C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Buenas espero que me puedan ayudar, estoy realizando una inserción pero al momento de insertar me sale el siguiente error.
**Parameter value 3420590313.72700000 is out of range**

mi Store procedure que realiza la insercion es decimal(19,8) y la columna que lo guarda es igual manera decimal (19,8)

Este es mi SP que guarda

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_qry_InsertarFlujo_SP]
@OPT                            int ,
@NumeroProceso                  Int,
@Periodo                        Int,
@Soles_VAC_Sobrevivencia        Decimal(19,8),
@Soles_Ajustados_Sobrevivencia  Decimal(19,8),
@Dolares_Sobrevivencia          Decimal(19,8),
@Soles_VAC_Invalidez            Decimal(19,8),
@Soles_Ajustados_Invalidez      Decimal(19,8),
@Dolares_Invalidez              Decimal(19,8),
@gastos_Sepelio_Invalidez_mantenimiento     Decimal(20,8)
as
    IF @opt=1
        BEGIN


            INSERT INTO Flujos_SP(Numero_Proceso,Periodo,Soles_VAC_Sobrevivencia,
                                  Soles_Ajustados_Sobrevivencia,Dolares_Sobrevivencia,
                                  Soles_VAC_Invalidez,Soles_Ajustados_Invalidez,
                                  Dolares_Invalidez,Gastos_Sepelio_Invalidez_mantenimiento)

            VALUES(@NumeroProceso,@Periodo,@Soles_VAC_Sobrevivencia,
                   @Soles_Ajustados_Sobrevivencia,@Dolares_Sobrevivencia,
                   @Soles_VAC_Invalidez,@Soles_Ajustados_Invalidez,
                   @Dolares_Invalidez,@gastos_Sepelio_Invalidez_mantenimiento)

         END
```

C#:

```
public bool InsertarFlujos(List<FlujoSP> listaFlujo,int numeroProceso)
{
    bool resultado = false;
    using (var transaccion = base.iniciarTransaccion())
    {
        foreach (var flujo in listaFlujo)
        {
            try
            {
                var parametro = new
                {
                    OPT=1,
                    NumeroProceso = numeroProceso,
                    Periodo = flujo.periodo,
                    Soles_VAC_Sobrevivencia = flujo.soles_VAC_Sobrevivencia,
                    Soles_Ajustados_Sobrevivencia = flujo.soles_Ajustados_Sobrevivencia,
                    Dolares_Sobrevivencia = flujo.dolares_Sobrevivencia,
                    Soles_VAC_Invalidez = flujo.soles_VAC_Invalidez,
                    Soles_Ajustados_Invalidez = flujo.soles_Ajustados_Invalidez,
                    Dolares_Invalidez = flujo.dolares_Invalidez,
                    gastos_Sepelio_Invalidez_mantenimiento = flujo.gastos_Sepelio_Invalidez_mantenimiento,

                };
                resultado = objEjecutar.Ejecutar(transaccion, Sp_InsertarFlujo, parametro, Constante.DuracionTimeOut) > 0 ? true : false;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                resultado = false;
                transaccion.Rollback();
                throw new Exception("No se insertar data de flujo del periodo : " + ex);
            }
        }
        transaccion.Commit();
    }
    return resultado;
}



public int32 numero_proceso {get;set;}
public int32 periodo{get;set;}
public decimal soles_vac_sobrevivencia{get;set;}
public decimal soles_ajustados_sobrevivencia{get;set;}
public decimal dolares_sobrevivencia{get;set;}
public decimal soles_vac_invalidez{get;set;}
public decimal soles_ajustados_invalidez{get;set;}
public decimal dolares_invalidez{get;set;}
public decimal gastos_sepelio_invalidez_mantenimiento{get;set;}
```

Comment: @PieroDev sugiero que si vas a hacer uso de cantidades hagas uso del tipo de dato `MONEY`, justo para eso fue diseñado ya que no pierde precisión

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87827/discussion-on-question-by-pierodev-parameter-value-is-out-of-range-c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debido a que los datos que almacenas son cantidades monetarias, es altamente recomendado hacer uso de un tipo de dato [`decimal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) para el caso de C#, ya que tiene una longitud de 128 bits, es decir, podrás almacenar hasta 28-29 dígitos. Incluso si deseas hacer un casteo a `long` o `double`, no perderás presición.

El tipo de dato equivalente en SQL Server, es [`MONEY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), y de igual manera, no pierde presición al hacer un casteo a otro tipo de dato.

Si deseas conocer un poco más acerca de equivalencias en tipos entre C# y SQL Server, podrás consultar [esta gran respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/968734/3200493).

Comment: como puedo hacer con el long  es que lo que pasa que ya se ha definido ea cantidad de 18,8 en la tabla de base de datos y no se puede modificar

Comment: @PieroDev Google es tu mejor aliado para saber cómo hacer un `CAST`